# How do you debug the Intellij vim plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

The vim plugin is broken, but only when opening certain language files.

I can't seem to delete most characters- but I can delete brackets.

It's extremely frustrating and I can't find how to see what is getting in the way of the vim mappings.

If I move over text and type `x` nothing is deleted but sometimes it is if the text is near a `{`. I have no idea what is happening- can I turn on debugging output for the vim plugin?

Comment: I would report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM with the steps to reproduce.

Comment: Im having trouble 100% reproducing it myself. How can you see some kind of debug output when typing keys? I don't want to wait for someone to pickup my issue to get this to work.

Comment: You can get IntelliJ IDEA Community source code, build and run it from the IDE via debugger.